# Поточное воспроизведение звука с помощью threading

Tags: python

```
class Music(Thread):
    def __init__(self,freq,time=500):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.freq=freq
        self.time=time
    def run(self):
        if self.freq>=37:
            Beep(self.freq,self.time)
def play(*notes):
    for note in notes:
        Music(notes_dict[note]).start()
play('до6','ре#3','ля5')
```

notes_dict это словарь с ключами-названиями нот и соответствующими значениями-частотами:

{'ля−1': 28, 'ля♯−1': 29, 'си−1': 31, 'до0': 33, ...}

и т.д..Я ожидал одновременного воспроизведения нот,но все ноты сыграли последовательно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beep не умеет смешивать звуки.